# Mean of data from histogram where the last bucket's range is "older than 20 years"

Tags: statistics, means

A friend is preparing for an exam where you are asked to compute the arithmetic mean and the mode of the following data (simplified):

```
 0-10 years: 10 people
10-20 years: 20 people  
  >20 years: 10 people
```

I see how to get the mode, but isn't it impossible to calculate the mean since one doesn't know enough about the last bucket?

Comment: Yes, finding the mean--even approximately--is impossible. The oldest person could be 21 or 101 years old.

Comment: @BruceET Ok thank you for the confirmation